# Any free evening parking in downtown Denver?

Tags: budget, automobiles, denver

I don't mind walking 15 to 20 minutes to where I need to be in downtown Denver, but it'll be useful to find some free street parking, during the evening time, 21:00/03:00 MT.

Any such thing in Denver, Colorado, the USA?

Comment: What do you consider to be the boundaries of downtown? Are you looking for free street parking within 15 to 20 minutes of that boundary? Or to be within 15 to 20 minutes of a destination? One reason I ask is that you could take advantage of the free Mall Ride which runs from just beyond Union Station through downtown to Civic Center Station near the capital. If that is included in your budgeted time, that could open up the search area. http://www.rtd-denver.com/FREEMallRide.shtml

Answer (score 3):

For many years prior to March 2011, you could park for free on the streets in downtown Denver, from 22:00 until 02:00, but there was no street parking between 02:00 and 06:00 (supposedly for street sweeping).  Almost every single web-resource you find nowadays, two years later (April/May 2013), still insists that parking between 22:00 and 02:00 is free, but that you always have to leave by 02:00; not the case at all.

Since about mid 2011, street parking between 22:00 and 02:00 is no longer free, but is 1$/h, and 0.50$/h between 02:00 and 06:00, and free between 06:00 and 08:00; the smart meters take credit cards.  (Street sweeping takes place on different days for different streets, such that overnight parking is always possible.)  The exception is Sunday: after 23:59 on Saturday, you can park for free for a number of hours, on all city streets.

Source: http://www.westword.com/2011-10-13/news/denver-overnight-parking-meters-confusing/

Comment: btw, this is a partial answer, which doesn't actually answer the question yet, but just provides a starting point for now. :)